# How to create owner/server for booking app

Tags: server

Guys really need your help I’m a beginner and don’t have any idea on how to create a owner or server for my project (photography booking app) I already started to create a client apps to make a log in or create a request/ book.. but how can I make a server or owner app who can see the request from client app. Can you please give me a tips or instruction not only on how to do it but the most is to understand how it really works Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

You've not really provided much info to go off (for example, what if any languages you're already comfortable using). There's probably too much to cover to explain here.

That said, for creating a backend, I personally found Flask pretty light and simple to get started with. There's also a really excellent tutorial series on it here: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins

Maybe start here?

Comment: Thanks for the info. I apologized for not giving a complete questions.. anyway I’m using android studio in my first project with java language, can you please give me some instruction related. So I have an idea on how to start it since I’m a beginner.. Thanks in advance